# upload binary file to redmine with node

Tags: node.js, rest, redmine

I try to upload a file to redmine with node, I can upload and attach text files, but when I try to upload a binary file I get the token but the file doesn't work. I tried with json, xml and binary, ascii, base64 encoding.

I want upload binary files because I'm doing end to end test testing I want open Issues with screenshots, and upload a report.

I'm using node-rest-client for service calling

Could someone give me any suggestion to fix this problem?

Thanks,

I define the class RMClient

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var Q = require('q');
var RMClient = function(baseUri, apiToken){
        this._apiToken = apiToken;
        var client = new Client();
        client.registerMethod('openIssue', baseUri+'/issues.json', 'POST');
        client.registerMethod('uploadFile', baseUri+'/uploads.json', 'POST');
        client.registerMethod('getIssues', baseUri+'/issues.json', 'GET');
        this._client = client;
};
```

option 1:

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
var file fs.readFileSync(filePath);
//code for sending file to redmine uploads.json 
return deferred.promise;
```

Option 2

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
var rs = fs.createReadStream(filePath, {'flags': 'r', 'encoding': null, 'autoClose': true});
var size = fs.statSync(filePath).size;
var file = '';
rs.on('error', function(err){ 
  deferred.reject(err);
});
rs.on('data', function(chunk){ file += chunk; });
rs.on('end', function(){
 //code for sending file to redmine uploads.json 
});
return deferred.promise;
```

Code that I use to upload the file:

```
try{
    if(!file){
        throw new Error('File must\'nt be void');
    }
    var rmc = new RMClient(myRMURI, myAPItoken);
    var headers = {
        'X-Redmine-API-Key': rmc._apiToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Length': size
    };

    var args = {
        'data':file,
        'headers': headers
    };
    if(parameters){
        args.parameters = parameters;
    }

    rmc._client.methods.uploadFile(args, function(data, response){
        if(response.statusCode != 201){
            var err = new Error(response.statusMessage);
            deferred.reject(err);
            return;
        }

        var attach = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(attach);
        if(data.errors){
            var msg = ''.concat.apply('', attach.errors.map(function(item, i){
                return ''.concat(i+1,'- ',item,(i+1<attach.errors.length)?'\n':'');
            }));
            console.error(msg);
            deferred.reject(Error(msg));
        }else{
            deferred.resolve(attach.upload.token);
        }
    });
}catch(err){
    console.error(err);
    deferred.reject(err);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and solved it this way:

- Use "multer";
- When you have an uploaded file, make a request using node "request" module, with `req.file.buffer` as `body`.

Comment: I spend ages and this answer was what I was looking for. Many thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

Then uploading files using the [Rest API](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api#Attaching-files), you have to send the raw file contents in the request body, typically with `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`. The uploaded file doesn't need any further encoding or wrapping, esp. not as `multipart/form-data`, JSON or XML.

The response of the POST request to `/uploads.xml` contains the token to attach the attachment to other objects in Redmine.

Comment: I tried this, but still witout work, the file size isn't the same and the content is diferent. I get the file in this way `fs.readFileSync(filePath);` and also I tried getting it like this `var rs = fs.createReadStream(filePath, {'flags': 'r', 'encoding': null, 'autoClose': true});
 var size = fs.statSync(filePath).size;
 var file = ''
 
 
 rs.on('error', function(err){
  deferred.reject(err);
 })
 rs.on('data', function(chunk){
  file += chunk;
 });
 rs.on('end', function(){
 //code for sending file to redmine uploads.json
 });`  but doesn't work

Comment: Code in comments is not readable at all. Please edit your question and add your code there with proper formatting. Please also add the code you use to upload the data to Redmine.