# Structure xml of uploads.xml for redmine

Tags: xml, redmine

I am trying to create a issue with attachment( image file).
Before i create a issue, First i must send a request to upload.xml where i will get a token.

My question is :
How should xml structe looks like??

Thx for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33656051/421705